# Auto subscribe all site users to site blogs by default in Liferay

Tags: liferay, blogs, subscribe

In **Blog portlet** in **Liferay** I want all my **site users** must be by **default subscribed** to the **blogs** for the site. Is there any property that we could set, but i didn't find one. I am new to liferay, so if anybody could help that would be great.
thankyou.

Comment: i found something, it worked but I think not the correct way. I have overridden a Action & in that i have used a blog service:               **BlogsEntryLocalService bls=BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.getService();  bls.subscribe(userid, groupId);**  what I did was whenever there will be a site member assigned or removed i fetched all user ids & group ids & subscribed all the users, because i didn't get the list of only those users who get assigned, so that only those get subscribed, & don't know how to get those & where to write the code exactly